# How can I automate / script an update that modifies 100+ triggers at once (or in a loop)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ssms

### Summary

I am trying to figure out a way I can automatically alter 100+ triggers at once or in a loop.  The triggers are all identical except for the respective table that they are associated with.

### Details:

I have a SQL server database and I have 300+tables and over 100+ of those tables have a trigger that prevents anyone from deleting any records.
  As you can see below, trigger simply sets "IsDeleted" field to 1 if a person tries to do a delete (this way I never lose anything)

For example a trigger in my Person table would look like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [TD_Person]
ON [Person]
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE  x
SET [IsDeleted] = 1
FROM [Person] x
    INNER JOIN
        deleted d
        ON x.[Id] = d.[Id]
```

the issue is that i now realize that I need to update another field (besides IsDeleted) called LastUpdated (which is a datetime field) as part of this trigger.  This way, I am capturing the time in which the delete occurred

To make the change is quite simple.  Instead of just:

```
SET [IsDeleted] = 1
```

I would do this:

```
SET [IsDeleted] = 1, LastUpdated = GETDATE()
```

in the trigger above. I tested the change and it works fine.

My issue is that i don't want to manually go into each of my table and have paste ", LastUpdated = GETDATE()" into the trigger one by one.

I can isolate these triggers by doing something like this:

```
Select * 
FROM sys.triggers t
where t.Name like 'MyDeleteTrigger_%'
ESCAPE '\'
```

but I can't figure out how I could leverage this to modify each of these triggers?

Is there any way to somehow automate this update to a trigger that exists in so many tables to avoid tedious copy and paste over again?

Comment: You can script out all 100 triggers using Object Explorer > Database > Generate Scripts, but there's no magic way to adopt these 100 triggers for you - you'll have to do that manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following query in order to automatically change your triggers:

```
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT  @Command = @Command +
        'ALTER TRIGGER [TD_'+OBJECT_NAME(t.parent_id)+']'+CHAR(13) +
        'ON ['+OBJECT_NAME(t.parent_Id)+']'+CHAR(13) +
        'INSTEAD OF DELETE'+CHAR(13)+
        'AS'+CHAR(13)+
        'SET NOCOUNT ON'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(13)+
        'UPDATE  x'+CHAR(13)+
        'SET [IsDeleted] = 1, LastUpdated = GETDATE()'+CHAR(13)+
        'FROM ['+OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.parent_id)+'].['+OBJECT_NAME(t.parent_id)+'] x'+CHAR(13)+
        'INNER JOIN deleted d ON x.[Id] = d.[Id]'+CHAR(13)+
        'End;'+CHAR(13)
FROM sys.triggers t
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE is_instead_of_trigger = 1
    and m.definition like '%INSTEAD OF DELETE%'

--SELECT @Command

EXEC(@Command)
```

Comment: This script actually work against the `sys.triggers` which provides you with the list of triggers within your database. What gets the triggers updated is that `alter trigger` statement right on top of it all. It will be run against all `instead of delete` triggers. The `select` statement simply build the command to be run concatenated with the other information required to target the right object. Then, it gets executed by the `exec()` or `execute()` command at the end.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller. Thanks for your comment and explain exactly.

Comment: I went with a slightly different approach but this answer allowed me to figure it out so i have accepted it (leveraged the sys.triggers table) and with a bit of export to excel, find replace, and copy and paste back in . . A bit safer for my mind :)